# How do you handle nontrivial environment differences with docker?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I recognize that docker is intended to reduce the friction of moving an application from one environment to another, and in many cases doing things like overriding environment variables is pretty easy at runtime.

Consider a situation where all development happens behind a corporate proxy, but then the images (or containers or Dockerfiles) need to be shipped to a different environment which has different architecture requirements.  The specific case I'm thinking of is that the development environment includes a pretty invasive corporate proxy.  The image needs (in order to function) the ability to hit services on the internet, so the working Dockerfile looks something like this in development:

```
FROM centos

ENV http_proxy=my.proxy.url \ 
    https_proxy=my.proxy.url \

# these lines required for the proxy to be trusted, most apps block it otherwise b/c SSL inspection
COPY ./certs/*.pem /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/
RUN /usr/bin/bupdate-ca-trust extract

## more stuff to actually run the app, etc
```

In the production environment, there is no proxy and no need to extract pem files.  I recognize that I can set the environment variables to not use the proxy at runtime (or conversely, set them only during development), but either way this feels pretty leaky to me in terms of the quasi-encapsulation I expect from Docker.

I recognize as well that this particular example, it's not *that* big a deal to copy and extract the pem files that won't be used in production, but it made me wonder about best practices in this space, as I'm sure this isn't the only example.

Ideally I would like to let the host machine manage the proxy requirements (and really, any environment differences), but I haven't been able to find a way to do that except by modifying environment variables.

Comment: Are you using `docker-compose` for development?

Comment: @Rawkode in some cases yes, in some cases no.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/systemd/#httphttps-proxy

Comment: @Rawkode that only solves the environment variable part of the problem, which as i said is easily overcome in other ways.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use `iptables` on your development machine to proxy traffic from containers to a proxy. Then your image would be the same in each environment it runs in, the network differences would be managed by the host. See http://silarsis.blogspot.nl/2014/03/proxy-all-containers.html for more information.

IMO I wouldn't worry too much about it if it works. Image still runs in every environment so you're not really "giving something up" other than semantics :)

Answer (score 0):

You can probably configure this at the Docker Engine level, using the instruction at: https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/systemd/#httphttps-proxy

> Create a systemd drop-in directory for the docker service:

```
$ mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
```

> Create a file called /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf that adds the HTTP_PROXY environment variable:

```
[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.example.com:80/"
```

> Or, if you are behind an HTTPS proxy server, create a file called
>   /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/https-proxy.conf that adds the
>   HTTPS_PROXY environment variable:

```
[Service]
Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=https://proxy.example.com:443/"
```

> If you have internal Docker registries that you need to contact without
>   proxying you can specify them via the NO_PROXY environment variable:

```
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.example.com:80/"
"NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1,docker-registry.somecorporation.com"
```

> Or, if you are behind an HTTPS proxy server:

```
Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=https://proxy.example.com:443/"
"NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1,docker-registry.somecorporation.com"
```

> Flush changes:

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload Restart Docker:
$ sudo systemctl restart docker
```

> Verify that the configuration has been loaded:

```
$ systemctl show --property=Environment docker
Environment=HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.example.com:80/
```

> Or, if you are behind an HTTPS proxy server:

```
$ systemctl show --property=Environment docker
Environment=HTTPS_PROXY=https://proxy.example.com:443/
```

Comment: As I said in response to your comment, this doesn't solve the main issue, where I'm copying and extracting pem files.  Further, there's nothing in the documentation that I could find or that you've posted that suggests this affects how the containers connect to the internet rather than how the daemon itself works.